# How to setup a Raspberry Pi to make media files of hard drive available everywhere?

Tags: hard-drive, media-server

### **What I want**

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi 3 attached to my home router to make available a hard drive with a bunch of media files (pictures and videos) to all my devices. (kind of a homemade Dropbox)

Considerations:

- **Everywhere**: it should work whether I'm in my home network or not.
- **Phone client:** I would prefer to have a client that can download the content so I can after play it rather than directly stream it.

### **Research I have done**

I've been doing some research for the last few days but I didn't come across a satisfactory way of doing it. The two options I found are:

- **Plex:** it will stream the files and I'm concern about the performance. I probably wouldn't see a HD video without problems.
- **NAS:** only available in the home network.

What is the best way to achieve this? If there is one..

**Update:**

I found ownCloud and nextCloud and look really close to what I want.

Comment: Do you want to stream or download?

Comment: download if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NextCloud (https://nextcloud.com ), a fork of OwnCloud which you can install on your pi, or  just flash a prepared disk image for the pi:
https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/13/nextcloud-ready-raspberry-pi-image/

Seems promising, but i haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to use it but it doesn't have ssh enable by default so it's useless for me (I don't have external display and keyboard). I will try to install nextCloud by myself now

Comment: Well having it enabled by default would mean that it would be accessible with default password, which calls for disaster. Vanilla Raspbian is the same, so how do you get around in that situation? I sometimes use a TV and a media player keyboard or a USB to serial cable (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/overview ) to configure networking and enable ssh.

Comment: According to https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/ (Option 3) you can enable ssh on the /boot partition, by creating a dummy file named "ssh". But i see you got the same answer already on  https://github.com/nachoparker/nextcloud-raspbian-generator/issues/4 :)

Comment: yeah I know, but it was broken. It's fixed now -> https://github.com/nachoparker/nextcloud-raspbian-generator/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got 3 separate problems:
1) How to use a Pi on your home router to store data: I just recently set up [OpenMediaVault](http://www.openmediavault.org/) & it worked well. I could stream HD over wifi to my TV.
2) How to make it visible outside your house: this comes down to two things - a static IP address and opening the right ports for external access. There is a discussion on the [OpenMediaVault forum](http://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/10832-Accessing-Samba-shares-from-outside-home-network/) with someone who wants to do this and ends up with OpenVPN. 
3) A downloading client on your phone - not sure about this bit. Sounds like a dropbox sync to me.